# SQL: execute changes in inner joins AFTER changes in a row values of table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-update, inner-join

My question is somewhat conceptual.

I have a procedure on SQL where I join a few tables together. As an example: "mkt_Original" contains codes (A1,A3,etc) while "mkt_Desc" contains descriptors (Aruba, Argentina, etc). They are joined by an inner join and added to a temporary table:

```
SELECT CountryDesc, ColumnX into mkt_Temp 
FROM mkt_Original 
INNER JOIN mkt_Desc ON Mkt_Original.CountryCode = mkt_Desc.CountryCode
```

After generating the temporary table, I do a few changes to the country codes depending on the values of the other columns (ColumnX). For example:

```
UPDATE mkt_Temp
SET mkt_Temp.CountryCode = A3
WHERE mkt_Temp.ColumnX = 3
```

However, once i'm done with all the updates, i'm curious as to how the Country "description" will update (because now theres another country code). For example if originally the value A4 was stored it would bring back Japan and when I update to A3 it should say China.

Do I have to run another INNER JOIN query between the temporary table and all the other ones or is there a more efficient way? I was reading about Triggers but i'm not sure how one for this situation would look like. Any help or code for a trigger would be very useful!

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: You really want to do another query with an `inner join` to get the up-to-date data -- unless you are working with some incredibly large data volume.  Anything else sounds like needless complication.

Answer (score 0):

If i were you I will be writing a case statement in the join condition itself if there are not a lot of changes

```
SELECT CountryDesc, ColumnX into mkt_Temp 
FROM mkt_Original 
INNER JOIN mkt_Desc
ON (case when Mkt_Original.CountryCode = (case 
                                             when ColumnX = 3 then  'A3' else
                                          mkt_Desc.CountryCode end)
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately there are a LOT of previous changes and they are all different so I'm thinking writing a ton of case statements would be much more effort than necessary!